# SQL - Get all rows with same ID

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to get all rows with the same id, 
this is a example of the table:

```
Curs_ID     Cursistnr   payed
Excel       2           500
Internet    3           100
C#          2           200
```

what I want to get out of the table is everything where `Cursistnr` is 2
So what I need is 2 rows out of it:

```
Excel       2           500
C#          2           200
```

EDIT:

Oke, let me ask the question different.
this is the table:

```
curs_code|Cursistnr|cijfer|payed
Internet     50      5     2000.00
Internet     88      7     2000.00
Word         50      9     3300.00
Word         88      9     3300.00
Niam         88      6     850.00
```

I try to get everything from every row with cursistnr 88 for example
So:

Internet, 88 , 7, 2000.00
Niam, 88, 6, 850.00
word, 88, 9, 3300.00

If I try SELECT * FROM c_regel WHERE cursistnr='$id'

I only get:

```
array (size=8)
'curs_code' => string 'Internet' (length=8)
0 => string 'Internet' (length=8)
'cursistnr' => string '88' (length=2)
1 => string '88' (length=2)
'cijfer' => string '7' (length=1)
2 => string '7' (length=1)
'betaald' => string '2000.00' (length=7)
3 => string '2000.00' (length=7)
```

the php code I'm using:

```
function cursusDone($magazijn, $id){
  $sql = "SELECT curs_code FROM c_regel WHERE cursistnr='$id'";
  $query = $magazijn->query($sql);
  return $query->fetch();
}

$done = cursusDone($magazijn,$id);
var_dump($done);
```

I think it has something to do with the sql table,

if I try SELECT * FROM c_regel I only get te first row.
Don't know what's wrong here

Comment: This is not a write-me-the-code service, show us what you tried and what didn't work, this is very basic SQL task.

Comment: Are you really asking that?

Comment: Your last bit looks like a php var_dump. Please show some php code

Comment: There you go, added my php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very sure that `$query->fetch();` does only fetch the first row of your result.

If you could try this modified version of your `cursusDone` function:

```
function cursusDone($magazijn, $id){
  $sql = "SELECT curs_code FROM c_regel WHERE cursistnr='$id'";
  $query = $magazijn->query($sql);
  var_dump($query->fetch());
  var_dump($query->fetch());
  //return $query->fetch();
}
```

This should output the first two rows of your resultset as an array dump.

If i am right you could iterate through `$query->fetch()` until it returns false or an empty array (depends on the inner workings of your database class).

Comment: I've changed $query->fetch() into $query->fetchAll. that worked, When you told me that fetch() does only fetch the first row I Immediately thought about fetchAll, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Curs_ID, payed
FROM TAB -- insert your table
WHERE Cursistnr = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Add a basic `WHERE` statement

```
SELECT Curs_ID, Cursistnr, payed
FROM yourtable
WHERE Cursistnr = 2
```